# Creating a report in MySQL involving three tables

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate, reporting

In short, I am looking to create a report that shows a list of clients down the side (rows), with our services across the top (columns). In each cell, there will be a number, which represents a 'conversation type'. The idea is for our sales guys to be able to see -- if a client is aware of a particular service we offer, if they're live with it, if they've tried it and hate it, etc (these are conversation types). This is in an effort to avoid bombarding clients with the same information over and over. In essence, it's to be a tool the sales team can use to stay on the same page, internally.

Here are my tables:

services (id, service_name, description)
clients (id, client_name)
conversations (id, client_id, service_id, conversation_type_id)
conversation_type (id, description)

And here's my query so far:

```
SELECT 
company,
CASE WHEN service_name= 'A' THEN conversation_type_id END AS 'A', 
CASE WHEN service_name= 'B' THEN conversation_type_id END AS 'B',
CASE WHEN service_name= 'C' THEN conversation_type_id END AS 'C',
CASE WHEN service_name= 'D' THEN conversation_type_id END AS 'D' 
FROM 
services srv
INNER JOIN 
conversations con ON srv.id=con.service_id
INNER JOIN company cmp ON con.client_id=cmp.id
INNER JOIN conversation_type typ ON con.conversation_type_id=typ.id
GROUP BY company;
```

It seems close, but instead of it printing

```
----------------------------------------------
|          | A      | B      | C      | D     |
|client 1  | 1      | 2      | 1      | 5     |
|client 2  | 3      | 2      | 3      | 4     |
|client 3  | 1      | 5      | 1      | 1     |
-----------------------------------------------
```

it instead prints

```
----------------------------------------------
|          | A      | B      | C      | D     |
|client 1  | 1      |        |        |       |
|client 1  |        | 2      |        |       |
|client 1  |        |        | 1      |       |
|client 1  |        |        |        |   5   |
-----------------------------------------------
```

I guess it's a grouping issue, but I've tried all sorts of things and it doesn't seem to be agreeable. Any ideas? And really, is there a better way to do this? Would really appreciate any insight. Thank you.

Comment: That would be (e.g.) MAX(CASE WHEN...END) 'A', etc. As for better ways, yes. Issues of data display are generally best handled in the presentation layer / application-level code, assuming that's available (e.g. a simple PHP loop on a well-formed array)

Comment: it would help if you could show the examples of the actual data in the FROM table

Comment: Thank you Strawberry! I do not understand why this works, but it works! Could you recommend an article I could read about MAX(CASE WHEN...END)? I really need to get better at understanding how to build reports and work with aggregate functions, and I am kind of a newb at this point. You seem to know what you're talking about, so any recommended reading I would really appreciate!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as  Strawberry said by putting Max(case ...) for each case. OR you can do it by putting each case in a query then joining them, like this (the first one definitely is better):

```
SELECT Z.Company, A,B,C,D 
FROM 
(SELECT 
company,
CASE WHEN service_name= 'A' THEN conversation_type_id END AS 'A'
FROM 
services srv
INNER JOIN 
conversations con ON srv.id=con.service_id
INNER JOIN company cmp ON con.client_id=cmp.id
INNER JOIN conversation_type typ ON con.conversation_type_id=typ.id
GROUP BY company) Z,
(SELECT 
company,
CASE WHEN service_name= 'B' THEN conversation_type_id END AS 'B'
FROM 
services srv
INNER JOIN 
conversations con ON srv.id=con.service_id
INNER JOIN company cmp ON con.client_id=cmp.id
INNER JOIN conversation_type typ ON con.conversation_type_id=typ.id
GROUP BY company) Y,
(SELECT 
company,
CASE WHEN service_name= 'C' THEN conversation_type_id END AS 'C'
FROM 
services srv
INNER JOIN 
conversations con ON srv.id=con.service_id
INNER JOIN company cmp ON con.client_id=cmp.id
INNER JOIN conversation_type typ ON con.conversation_type_id=typ.id
GROUP BY company) X,
(SELECT 
company,
CASE WHEN service_name= 'D' THEN conversation_type_id END AS 'D' 
FROM 
services srv
INNER JOIN 
conversations con ON srv.id=con.service_id
INNER JOIN company cmp ON con.client_id=cmp.id
INNER JOIN conversation_type typ ON con.conversation_type_id=typ.id
GROUP BY company) W
WHERE Z.company=Y.company
  AND Z.company=X.company
  AND Z.company=W.company
```

Comment: Yuck. Think I'll stick with plan A

Comment: Thanks for spelling it out though!